# Class App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to link a button in a user account page so they can reset their password. I created a form with the url `/password/reset` and pass along the email of the user but to see how the routes look for showing the reset password form when I run the command

```
php artisan route:list
```

I get the error

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController does not exist
```

I tried remaking auth by `php artisan make:auth` but this didn't solve the problem. Why would it be thinking the controller isn't in `app/http/Controllers/Auth/`? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You don't need create any routes or views since it's all will be done for you when you the the make:auth command. remove any route and and view you have created for the reseting the password and go to `localhost:8000` You will get login and register links out of the box provided by laravel if you click the login link you wiil get a login form and a reset password link

Comment: Thanks but I already know all that. That doesn't help me because the users need to be able to do this through their account. Why wouldn't I even be able to use php artisan route:list ? It's throwing an error and that shouldn't happen

Comment: Can you show us your route registrations? Are you using `Route::auth()`?

Answer (score 0):

please check your controller and route.php file there could be syntax error

Comment: There's no syntax error, that would have been caught

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the class's namespace declaration didn't match the path of the file. It was:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;
```

While the file path was:

```
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController.php;
```

The `Auth` folder wasn't inside the `Api` folder so I either had to move the folder to there or change the namespace declaration to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```